# Firefox 89.0 64 bit won't run Facebook (and some other) videos

Tags: firefox, video, facebook

The first frame of the video flashes up for a fraction of a second then a black window with "Sorry, having problems playing this video" with a link labelled "Learn More" in the centre of the window.  None of the suggestions that come up under "Learn More" do anything useful.  This is on a 6-year or so old HP Pavilion laptop running Ubuntu 20.04 with all the currently available updates and upgrades installed.  quad core AMD 64 bit processor.  8 GB RAM, lots of free hard disk space.

Comment: Did you install `ubuntu-restricted-extras`?

Comment: Nope.  I tried restarting firefox in Troubleshooting mode.  No difference. FB videos still comeup with that message.

Comment: ubuntu-restricted-extras contains the codecs required for playing videos and other media...  `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: That worked!  FB videos are playing again like normal.   Thank you!

Comment: I'll post that as an answer if you'd care to accept it.

Comment: Yes.  I'm not sure what that entails, but of course I accept that answer since it resolved the problem.   Ok.  I figured out what that check-mark was for.  Accepted.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ubuntu-restricted-extras` contains the codecs required for playing videos and other media.

It can be loaded by opening a terminal and typing:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`